# How to import a video from a directory?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have linked a video thru iframe tag in asp.net locally it works, but after deploying in server it doesn't. Need your help please. 
enter image description here

```
<div style="float:right ; position:relative; top: -145px ; right:8px;">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td><p align="left"><strong>Where the good ideas come from?</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
      <td> <iframe src="images/videos.mp4" width="280" height="240" align="right"></iframe> </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you verify the video exists at the URL?

Comment: it gives this error.  Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: that means the video is not uploaded to your server. I would recommend doing that, I'm not aware of your setup so can't say much about that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that video exists on the server in the images folder.

Another problem is you are using a relative path "images/videos.mp4" and a lot of times when you run an website locally it is inside of a directory that is different from the server.

Either change it to an absolute path "/images/videos.mp4" or `System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("images/videos.mp4")` to make sure the correct url is set.

```
<div style="float:right ; position:relative; top: -145px ; right:8px;">
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><p align="left"><strong>Where the good ideas come from?</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td> <iframe src='<%=System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("images/videos.mp4")' width="280" height="240" align="right"></iframe> </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

From new comments, the `404.3` error server means that the server is not configured to server files with and .MP4 extension. You will need to configure either the server or your website to server files with this extension.

Comment: Are you familiar with browser developer tools. Can you open it (F12) and look on the network tab. What is the response from the server when you load your page for that video request. Also, from the inspector tab both locally and on the server, what is actual rendered src attribute of the iframe tag.

Comment: You need to configure your server to allow MP4 files to be served. What is your webserver? IIS on a windows server? What version of IIS if so?